# How to stop Firebase database infinite looping

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an app and part of it's features in user interaction. I want to store user comments on a post and I do not want to limit the amount of comments any one user can make. I do this by assigning a random number as the `.setValue` of the database entry.

With this implementation, whenever the comment is sent to the database it is stuck in an infinite loop where it will continually update with the same string entered in the text box but it will constantly generate new posts.
Full code;

```
        sendComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            commitPost();
            finish();
        }
    });

}

private void commitPost() {
    commentProgress.setMessage("Posting");
    commentProgress.show();
    final String commentInput = commentText.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(commentInput)){
        Snackbar.make(commentLayout,"You haven't finished your post yet",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }else{

        commentDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                commentDB.child(postID).child("Comments").child(uniqueId).setValue(commentInput);
                commentProgress.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem lies in the `commentDB.addValueEventListener`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you set a listener for data changes and you also change data inside it (so it is called).

You don't need the listener, just add:

```
else {
    String uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    commentDB.child(postID)
             .child("Comments")
             .child(uniqueId)
             .setValue(commentInput); 
    commentProgress.dismiss();
}
```